# Add photogallery in Cartodb Infowindow?

Tags: carto, infowindow

Can I add a photogallery in the Cartodb Infowindow?

I know how to add an image (single) in the infowindow, but can a photogallery be added as well? Small thumbnails that become larger when clicked?

Can this be done with an iframe or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

This would require adding some scripts to your infowindow, and right now iframes or scripts are sanitized from the infowindows that you can create in the CartoDB Editor.

In order to achieve this you would need to generate a map with CartoDB.js, the CartoDB Javascript library, and then customize your infowindows. Notice there's a specific property to disable the sanitization, which will allow you to add your own scripts in the infowindows.

More info here:

CartoDB.js docs: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html
SanitizeTemplate option: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#attributes